# Random QRCode generator

Tags: android, qr-code

How can I implement a random QRCode into a specific activity (MainActivity) in Android using Eclipse? I need a QRCode generator in the activity which creates QRCodes on random value.

Comment: Yes. Sorry meant of random value.

Comment: Yes. Sorry meant of random value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library. it can be used to create QR codes as well as process QR code data input from the camera.

this is the library used by the [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) app.